# Sharing issue in PWA Angular4 apps

Tags: angular

How Invite Friend feature will work in PWA as in Native apps we just show the default sharing options ? Can we show default sharing options in PWA too ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want do say about "sharing options" ?

If you talk about social sharing ( share with facebook, tweeter... ), these fonctionnalities are independant to the way of create app.

It's an external additionnal API included to the APP.

So they can work with PWA, cause PWA is a web app.

Comment: Can PWA handle device sharing property like whataApp, twitter,etc. ??

Comment: Yes thanks to Notification API for example however PWA can't communicate with other app